# any web javascript iphone-like navigation component?

Tags: javascript, iphone, navigation

I am looking for a component to create real web pages (on computers) that looks like the iphone navigation menu. If you see image attached I mean the left menu (Inbox, Today, Next, etc)...

Image:
http://http://a6.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/024/Purple/ab/45/91/mzl.pchxslnz.480x480-75.jpg

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuery mobile which has a number of mobile / iphone like components that can also be used on the web. It is available http://jquerymobile.com/